# Parse.com Query works on local host but not on Google App Engine with Twilio and Php

Tags: php, google-app-engine, parse-platform, twilio

I've got some code that uses twilio to sign up users to a database on parse.com. I want to see if they phone number is already in my database. I set up a query to do it. the find() method messes up my code. It will work fine on my local host but as soon as I serve it on google app engine it throws an exception? try/catch statements dont help either. any advice?

I am total noob with this stuff. I dont know php/parse/twilio/google app engine at all. am I forgetting a library or something?

```
<?php 
require 'twilio-php/Services/Twilio.php';
require 'vendor/autoload.php'; 
use Parse\ParseClient;
use Parse\ParseObject;
use Parse\ParseQuery;
use Parse\ParseACL;
use Parse\ParsePush;
use Parse\ParseUser;
use Parse\ParseInstallation;
use Parse\ParseException;
use Parse\ParseAnalytics;
use Parse\ParseFile;
use Parse\ParseCloud;

date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
ParseClient::initialize('secret1','secret2', 'secret3');
$AccountSid = "secret4";
$AuthToken = "secret5";
$client = new Services_Twilio($AccountSid, $AuthToken);

$name = ($_REQUEST['Body']);
$from = ($_REQUEST['From']);

$query = new ParseQuery("RegisteredUsers");
$query->equalTo("PhoneNumber", (float)$from);
$results = $query->find();
$times = count($results);
echo $times;
$response = new Services_Twilio_Twiml();
$response->sms("Got your number in my database, $times times.");
echo $response;

$registeredUsers = new ParseObject("RegisteredUsers");
$registeredUsers->set("PhoneNumber", (float)$from);
$registeredUsers->set("GuestName", $name);
$registeredUsers->save();

?>
```

Comment: Do you mind posting the exception? It would definitely be useful here :).

Comment: There is no exception. I'm just assuming something crashes out because when I add the find() method, I am no longer able to respond with an sms using the twilio sdk. So basically, the find() is throwing an exception. in a try/catch statement I am not able to catch and then echo a print statement. It wont show anything. not sure whats up

Comment: Like I said, it works perfectly when I run it out of terminal. so something to do with serving it.

Comment: okay, when I serve it local host I get this exception: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Parse\ParseException' with message 'No URL set!'